# Web API routing with DTO object - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have two projects, one is SPA and the other one is ASP.NET aspx project.
Normally those two projects communicate with each other via web API.

There is a running method like this (from SPA to ASP.NET)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("DenyInvoice/{approvalId:long}")]
    public IHttpActionResult DenyInvoice(long approvalId)
    {
        string exMsg = "";

        if (DenyInvoice(approvalId, this.UserId, this.Email, out exMsg))
            return Ok();

        return BadRequest(exMsg);
    }
```

This method works as I wanted, but I want to write a method that accepts a DTO variable like;

```
    [HttpPost]    
    [Route("InvoiceDetailUpdate/{invoices : invoiceDetailDtoModel}")]
    public IHttpActionResult InvoiceDetailUpdate(invoices : invoiceDetailDtoModel)
    {
        ....
    }
```

Is it possible? How should I do this?

Can you help?
Thank you..

Comment: What do you mean DTO object? Is that an object of a class that you have defined?

Comment: Yes, i mean a class that i defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[FromBody]` to pass in the POST parameter. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api#implement-the-other-crud-operations for more details.

```
[HttpPost]    
[Route("InvoiceDetailUpdate")]
public IHttpActionResult InvoiceDetailUpdate([FromBody]InvoiceDetailDtoModel invoices)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to retrieve parameter via post so there is no required for get parameter routing.

```
[HttpPost]    
[Route("InvoiceDetailUpdate")]
public IHttpActionResult InvoiceDetailUpdate(InvoiceDetailDtoModel invoices)
{
    ....
}
```

Also, be careful with the name convention of a class.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, you can use like this :

```
  public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/books")]
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks() { ... }

    [Route("api/books/{id:int}")]
    public Book GetBook(int id) { ... }

    [Route("api/books")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateBook(Book book) { ... }
}
```

Now , you can see this link [attribute-routing-in-web-api-2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)
and change your code to above figure

```
  [Route("api/YourController/InvoiceDetails")]
 public IHttpActionResult InvoiceDetailUpdate(InvoiceDetails invoiceDetailsDto)
```